# How to setting mongodb to store data in other disk

Tags: mongodb, express

currently, I install mongodb on the C Drive and everytime I use backend to store something in mongodb, it will be automatically stored in the same folder as mongodb, which is C:/.
But my next project will have to store a huge data of video and image, and if i keep save it on C:/, it will be full in no time.
How can I config mongo and express so that my data will be stored in E:/(External memory)

I don't want to install mongo on E:/, just want to store data on E:/, to save memory for my C drive

Comment: You can define the path at [storage.dbPath](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.dbPath)